# How can I add and use bootstrap to an ionic 4 app?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ionic4

I am building an ionic 4 application, and I want to use bootstrap without using the CDN method. I have installed bootstrap with npm install bootstrap.

Comment: Have you followed this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215970/4813913

Comment: @ManojKumar yes i have its giving this error after adding import "bootstrap"

./src/theme/variables.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/theme/variables.scss)
Module build failed: 
undefined
^
      Media query expression must begin with '('
      in C:\Users\src\theme\variables.scss (line 6, column 1)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With Ionic 4, this can be done easily by making use of the angular.json file

*open the angular.json* file, this can be located at the root of your project

locate the the styles array, add the path to the downloaded bootstrap file

```
"styles": [
          {
            "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
          },
          {
            "input": "src/global.scss"
          },
          {
            "input": "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          }
        ],
```

if you wish to make use of bootstrap scripts, add the bootstrap script to the scripts array as well.

**Please note:** for you to make use of bootstrap scripts, jquery and popper.js are required to be added to your projects as well

Answer (score 0):

1. create new folder public/css inside ionic app folder.
2. inside public/css paste copy of bootstrap.min.css.
3. add "public/css/bootstrap.min.css" string path in angular.json.

*make sure to rebuild your app .>ionic serve

[image: add-bootstrap-to-ionic4_1]

[image: add-bootstrap-to-ionic4_2]

Answer (score -2):

Just paste the [BootstrapCDN](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/) into the header of src/index.html.

Comment: this will require internet connection on mobile device.. remember ionic is also for mobile apps which not necessary have internet connection. Also OP said without using CDN.

Answer (score -7):

Go With Links.

[1.techiediaries](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-bootstrap-ui/)

[2.youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qy1gDOx0qPE)

and
 rerun ionic 4 using ionic serve