# I want to use bootstrap with my ionic 4 app

Tags: bootstrap-4, ionic4

I am building a  ionic 4 app 
and I want to use bootstrap with my app

How can I do it?

```
"styles": [
          {
            "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
          },
          {
            "input": "src/global.scss"
          },
          {
            "input": "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          }
        ],
```

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53063005/how-can-i-add-and-use-bootstrap-to-an-ionic-4-app

Answer (score 2):

just want to use css file from bootstrap, the most easy way is import it's css file in your global.scss like this

```
@import './theme/variables';
@import '../node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/ionic.bundle.css';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

change the angular.json is not needed.